# Visual Studio 2022 - Multiple monitor's layout (tabs and windows) save/load problem

Tags: visual-studio, layout, multiple-monitors

I have 3 monitors and their resolutions are: 2560x1080, 1440x900 and 1280x1024.

My problem is that I have a layout/setup for my tabs and windows on the 3 monitor in Visual Studio 2022 and I want them to load the same way whenever I start VS 2022. After I start, the previously set up layout is just not there and I need to start arrange again the tabs and my windows on the three monitor almost from scratch.

I tried the window/save window layout option but after I apply the previously saved window layout, VS just loads only one monitor's layout correct and the other two's are not the same way I set it up earlier. True, then you only need to arrange two monitor's tabs and windows again, but I would be happy if it would somehow load properly on the three monitors the same way I set it up before.

Is there any solution to this kind of problem, if it is what can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the position, size, and behavior of windows to create window layouts that work best for various development workflows in Visual Studio 2022. You can also personalize how you use tabs to interact with your code. When you customize a window layout, the Visual Studio integrated development environment (IDE) remembers it. For example, if you change the docking location of Solution Explorer and then close Visual Studio, the next time that you open Visual Studio, Solution Explorer will be docked in that same location. The Visual Studio IDE remembers the docking location even if you're working on another computer. You can also name and save a custom layout and then switch between layouts with a single command.

Visual Studio enables you to save up to 10 custom window layouts and quickly switch between them. You can create custom layouts that take advantage of multiple monitors with both docked and floating tool windows.

Here are the steps to create, save, invoke, and manage two custom layouts that take advantage of multiple monitors with both docked and floating tool windows:

1. Open Visual Studio.
2. Arrange your windows as desired.
3. On the Window menu, choose Save Window Layout.
4. In the Save Window Layout dialog box, enter a name for your layout.
5. Choose OK.
6. To apply a saved layout, on the Window menu, choose Apply Window Layout.
7. In the Apply Window Layout dialog box, choose your saved layout from the list.
8. Choose OK.